# Modified Summary Link Web Part

Tags: web-part

I'm migrating a heavily customized version of SharePoint 2010 (the master page is where most of the customization occurred) to 2016. The Summary Link Web Part is not displaying groups in columns in 2016 although it does in 2010. I think it has something to do with the additional Group Header Styles on the Summary Link Web part in 2010.

I would like to remove the customized summary link web part and reset it to the OOB version. Any help is appreciated!